# Need some input on Apex class

Tags: apex, salesforce-survey

I have a requirement to show all Survey questions/Answers in one single record. I have 5 survey questions. Once survey is completed I need to get all 5 answers and need to populate in different object called SurveyResult__c. SurveyResult__c object has 6 fields SurveyInvitationId and 5 questions as text fields. The issue I am facing with my code is I am getting

> "FATAL_ERROR|System.ListException: Duplicate id in list:"

Here is my code:

```
        List<SurveyResult__c> updateSurveyRec = new List<SurveyResult__c>();
        for(SurveyQuestionResponse suvQueRes : [SELECT ChoiceValue,Datatype,DateTimeValue,DateValue,Id,
                                                       InvitationId,NumberValue, QuestionChoiceId,QuestionId,                                                       
                                                       ResponseId,ResponseShortText,Rank,
                                                       ResponseValue,SurveyVersionId,Question.Name 
                                                  FROM SurveyQuestionResponse 
                                                 WHERE InvitationId IN :surveyMap.keySet()])
                  {
                    SurveyResult__c survRec = new SurveyResult__c();
                    
                    if(suvQueRes.Question.Name == 'Question1'){
                        survRec.Question1__c  = suvQueRes.ResponseValue;
                    }
                    if(suvQueRes.Question.Name == 'Question2'){
                        survRec.Question2__c = suvQueRes.ResponseValue;
                        
                    }
                    if(suvQueRes.Question.Name == 'Question3'){
                        survRec.Question3__c = suvQueRes.ResponseValue;
                        
                    }
                    if(suvQueRes.Question.Name == 'Question4'){
                        survRec.Question4__c = suvQueRes.ResponseValue;
                        
                    }
                    if(suvQueRes.Question.Name == 'Question5'){
                        survRec.Question5__c = suvQueRes.ResponseValue;
                        
                    }                              
                        survJun.Id = surveyJunMap.get(suvQueRes.InvitationId);
                        updateSurveyRec.add(survRec);                                                                         
                  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd argue that keeping the questions/responses in their own entities as they are now and making a lightning web component (or a visualforce page) to be able to show them all on a single page would be a superior design because that would keep you/the solution independent of the number of questions on the survey.

Sure you may have 5 questions now, but is that always going to be the case?

Anyway, setting that aside, the issue here should be pretty self-evident. If you have two (or more) `SurveyQuestionResponse` records with the same InvitationId, your `surveyJunMap` is going to return the same Id (I have to assume `surveyJunMap` is a `Map<Id, Id>` because you haven't given us enough context for your code. I also assume that `survJun.Id` should be `survRec.Id`).

Your loop isn't updating your `SurveyResult__c` record (in memory), it's creating a completely new instance (in memory) each iteration. So instead of ending up with `updateSurveyRec` containing

```
[
  SurveyResult__c(Id = theId, Question1__c = response1, Question2__c = response2)
]
```

You're getting

```
[
  SurveyResult__c(Id = theId, Question1__c = response1), 
  SurveyResult__c(Id = theId, Question2__c = response2)
]
```

and when you later (again, you haven't included enough context) `update updateSurveyRec;`, you run into the "duplicate id in list" error because you do in fact have records with duplicated Ids in your list.

The fatal flaw in your code as it stands is that you're using a List here when you really should be using a Map. It is possible to structure your code in a way where you could use a List, but really, Map is the right tool for the job.

With a Map, instead of creating new, separate instances of your SObject each time, you can create a new instance *once* and then re-use it. The usual map-building pattern applies.

A little example to get you going

```java
Map<Id, MySObject__c> sobjToUpdateMap = new Map<Id, MySObject__c>();
for(MySObject__c child :childRecordQuery){
    // The first time we encounter a key, add data to the map
    if(!sobjToUpdateMap.containsKey(child.ParentId)){
        sobjToUpdateMap.put(child.ParentId, new ParentObject__c());
    }

    // At this point, the map is guaranteed to contain a value for the key you
    //   have access to via the child record.
    // So, we can use map.get() without needing to perform any other checks.
    // Using SObject's .put() method is a little slower than using normal dot-notation
    //   but it can help us avoid long if-else if chains
    sobjToUpdateMap.get(child.ParentId).put(child.fieldName + '__c', child.interestingField__c);
}
```